# How to add up multiple "price" arrays to one?

Tags: php, html

How to addup the "preis/price" arrays to one number?
  Ive got a few items in the cart and now i want to addup the arrays from the while loop to get a total price.

its an school project and we use a old php version, dont ask why...

```
<?php

@$produktid =$_GET['id'];
$benutzer= $_SESSION['benutzer'];

@mysql_connect('localhost','root') OR DIE ('keine DB-Serveranmeldung');
@mysql_select_db('ivprojekt') OR DIE ('Keine DB-Anmeldung');

$hinein = "INSERT INTO warenkorb (db_warenkorb_produkte, db_warenkorb_benutzer)
                    VALUES ('$produktid', '$benutzer')";

@mysql_query($hinein) OR DIE ('kein DB-Eintrag');

$lesen = "SELECT db_warenkorb_produkte FROM warenkorb".
    " WHERE db_warenkorb_benutzer like '%$benutzer%'  ";

$abfrage = @mysql_query($lesen) OR DIE ('Lesen aus DB nicht möglich');

WHILE ($datensatz =mysql_fetch_array($abfrage))
{
    $produkteimwarenkorb = $datensatz['db_warenkorb_produkte'];

    $lesen2 = "SELECT * FROM produkt WHERE db_id like '$produkteimwarenkorb'";
    $abfrage2 = @mysql_query($lesen2) OR DIE ('Lesen aus DB nicht möglich');

    WHILE ($datensatz2 = mysql_fetch_array($abfrage2))
    {
        echo "<article>";
        echo "<table width='100%'>";
        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td align='center'>";
        echo "<h1>Art.-NR " . $datensatz2 ['db_id'] . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>" . $datensatz2 ['db_name'] . "</h2>";

        echo "Kategorie: " . $datensatz2 ['db_kategorie'];
        echo "</br>";
        echo $datensatz2 ['db_preis'] . " €";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "</td>";

        $preis = $datensatz2 ['db_preis'];

        $loesch = "SELECT db_warenkorb_id FROM warenkorb ".
            "WHERE db_warenkorb_benutzer = '$benutzer'";
        $loesch2 = @mysql_query($loesch) OR DIE ('Lesen aus DB nicht möglich');

        $loeschenx = mysql_fetch_array($loesch2);

        $loeschenx2 = $loeschenx['db_warenkorb_id'];

        echo "<td align='center'>";
        echo "<img width='200px' src='" . $datensatz2['db_bild']."' alt='Bild'>";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "<form action='loeschen.php'>".
            " <input type='image' src='bilder/loeschen.png' width='50px'>  ";
        echo "<input type='hidden' value= '$loeschenx2' name='loeschen'/></form>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</article>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Declare a variable such as `$total` outside the while loop and then inside the loop add that iterations amount to `$total`. Look into the `+=` operator!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code (total price at variable `$total`):

```
<?php

@$produktid =$_GET['id'];
$benutzer= $_SESSION['benutzer'];

@mysql_connect('localhost','root') OR DIE ('keine DB-Serveranmeldung');
@mysql_select_db('ivprojekt') OR DIE ('Keine DB-Anmeldung');

$hinein = "INSERT INTO warenkorb (db_warenkorb_produkte, db_warenkorb_benutzer)
                    VALUES ('$produktid', '$benutzer')";

@mysql_query($hinein) OR DIE ('kein DB-Eintrag');

$lesen = "SELECT db_warenkorb_produkte FROM warenkorb".
    " WHERE db_warenkorb_benutzer like '%$benutzer%'  ";

$abfrage = @mysql_query($lesen) OR DIE ('Lesen aus DB nicht möglich');

$total = 0;
WHILE ($datensatz =mysql_fetch_array($abfrage))
{
    $produkteimwarenkorb = $datensatz['db_warenkorb_produkte'];

    $lesen2 = "SELECT * FROM produkt WHERE db_id like '$produkteimwarenkorb'";
    $abfrage2 = @mysql_query($lesen2) OR DIE ('Lesen aus DB nicht möglich');

    WHILE ($datensatz2 = mysql_fetch_array($abfrage2))
    {
        echo "<article>";
        echo "<table width='100%'>";
        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td align='center'>";
        echo "<h1>Art.-NR " . $datensatz2 ['db_id'] . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>" . $datensatz2 ['db_name'] . "</h2>";

        echo "Kategorie: " . $datensatz2 ['db_kategorie'];
        echo "</br>";
        echo $datensatz2 ['db_preis'] . " €";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "</td>";

        $preis = $datensatz2 ['db_preis'];

        $total += $preis;

        $loesch = "SELECT db_warenkorb_id FROM warenkorb ".
            "WHERE db_warenkorb_benutzer = '$benutzer'";
        $loesch2 = @mysql_query($loesch) OR DIE ('Lesen aus DB nicht möglich');

        $loeschenx = mysql_fetch_array($loesch2);

        $loeschenx2 = $loeschenx['db_warenkorb_id'];

        echo "<td align='center'>";
        echo "<img width='200px' src='" . $datensatz2['db_bild']."' alt='Bild'>";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "<form action='loeschen.php'>".
            " <input type='image' src='bilder/loeschen.png' width='50px'>  ";
        echo "<input type='hidden' value= '$loeschenx2' name='loeschen'/></form>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</article>";
    }
}
?>
```